# Two way communication flutter webview and reactjs website

Tags: reactjs, flutter

How to get a button actions of a website in the reactjs to the flutter native from webview integration?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask an edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Webview can communicate with flutter app via JavascriptChannels. To create a javascript channel initialize your WebView like this:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: INITIAL_URL,
  javascriptChannels: [
    JavascriptChannel(name: 'Print', onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
      // here you decide what to do with the message
      setState(() {
        currentMessage = message;
      });
    }
  ]
)
```

Initializing WebView with 'Print' javacsript channel adds Print object to window scope. To post message to your flutter app just write:

```
Print.postMessage('Example message');
```